# batch file problem: pass powershell variable to batch

Tags: powershell, batch-file, hybrid

i have this hybris batch/powershell base64 decoder and i want to decode the string in powershell and set the decoded variable to a variable in batch, this is my code

```
@echo off
set syscall=dGVzdGluZ3hk
powershell.exe $decoded=[System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString([System.Convert]::FromBase64String($env:syscall));
```

Comment: Please do not vandalize posts on Stack Overflow, including your own. Content is licensed here under CC-BY-SA 4.0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a `for /f` statement to capture the output from a command (run `for /?` in a `cmd.exe` session for more information):

```
@echo off
set "syscall=dGVzdGluZ3hk"
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%i in (`powershell.exe -noprofile -c "[System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString([System.Convert]::FromBase64String($env:syscall))"`) do set "decoded=%%i"
```

After executing the above, `%decoded%` contains `testingxd`.

Comment: Do you know any *big* programming language(s)?

Comment: @AbrahamZinala, what makes a programming language big?

Comment: The more well-known, such as the low-level languages.

Comment: @AbrahamZinala I've worked with C and C++ in the past, but it's been many, many years.